# gulp configuration with WebStorm

Tags: gulp, webstorm

I'm confused between gulp and gulp cli and how to configure the right one with WebStorm in a right way. Please advise.

Screenshots with paths are below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The configuration should be as follows.

[image]